# Make SharePoint List read only for Non-Admin

Tags: permissions

I have a SharePoint web application which implements FBA. Users are given permission through another system. And that users are added to SharePoint web application.

I have a list to which all FBA users have edit rights currently. I want to implement security structure which allows following:

1. The list should not be allowed to be edited by these FBA users
2. Admin should be allowed to add items to this list via a timer job

Is there any way this can be implemented **except** adding all these users to a specific group and then assigning permissions?

Comment: Add those users in the visitors group of your site. Or make a group having "Read" or "Restricted Read" permissions and put that users in that group. So that they will not get any add edit permissions on the list.

Comment: At the same time you can also break the permissions for the list and assign the unique permissions for list.

Comment: Thanks. Problem is that users are directly added to site without being added to any user. So is there any way to achieve this without changing this current implementation.i.e without adding users to group?

Comment: Can I know the reason or is it in your requirement that not to add user in any of sharepoint groups...

Comment: It is in requirement itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing the item level permissions in the advanced settings of the list, there should be a section about who gets to edit and who gets to read which documents. This does not apply to document libraries I think.